# @InjectMocks behaving differently with Java 6 and 7

Tags: java, mockito, java-7, type-erasure, java-6

With a very simple Mockito run JUnit test and class I am seeing different output when the test is run with Java 1.6.0_32 and Java 1.7.0_04 and want to understand *why* this is happening. I suspect there is some type erasure going on but would like a definitive answer.

Here is my example code and instructions on how to run from the command line:

#### FooServiceTest.java

```
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.util.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooServiceTest {
  @Mock Map<String, String> mockStringString;
  @Mock Map<String, Integer> mockStringInteger;

  @InjectMocks FooService fooService;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JUnitCore().run(FooServiceTest.class);
  }

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void checkInjection() {
    when(mockStringString.get("foo")).thenReturn("bar");
    fooService.println();
  }
}
```

#### FooService.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class FooService {
  private Map<String, String> stringString = new HashMap<String, String>();
  private Map<String, Integer> stringInteger = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public void println() {
    System.out.println(stringString.get("foo") + " " + stringInteger);
  }
}
```

To compile and run this example:

- save the above into files
- download and put in the same directory [junit.4.10.jar](https://github.com/downloads/KentBeck/junit/junit-4.10.jar) and [mockito-all-1.9.0.jar](http://mockito.googlecode.com/files/mockito-all-1.9.0.jar)
- set PATH to include a JDK
- compile with `javac -cp junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar *.java`
- run with `java -cp .;junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar FooServiceTest`

I believe the output from above is `null {}` because [@InjectMocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) field injection cannot correctly resolve the types since they are both of type Map. **Is this correct**?

Now changing one of the mock names to match the field in the class should allow Mockito to find a match. For example changing

```
@Mock Map<String, Integer> mockStringInteger;
```

to

```
@Mock Map<String, Integer> stringInteger;
```

then compiling/running with Java 1.6.0_32 gives (IMHO the expected) output `bar stringInteger` but with 1.7.0_04 gives `null stringInteger`.

Here is how I am running it (from a command line in Windows 7):

```
E:\src\mockito-test>set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin"
E:\src\mockito-test>javac -cp junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar *.java
E:\src\mockito-test>java -cp .;junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar FooServiceTest
    bar stringInteger
E:\src\mockito-test>set PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin"
E:\src\mockito-test>javac -cp junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar *.java
E:\src\mockito-test>java -cp .;junit-4.10.jar;mockito-all-1.9.0.jar FooServiceTest
    null stringInteger
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I believe the output from above is I null {} because @InjectMocks field injection cannot correctly resolve the types since they are both of type Map. Is this correct?

Yes, correct on these field Mockito cannot clear the ambiguity, so it simply ignores these ambiguous fields.

> With a very simple Mockito run JUnit test and class I am seeing different output when the test is run with Java 1.6.0_32 and Java 1.7.0_04 and want to understand why this is happening.

Actually the diferrence resides in a different behavior of Arrays.sort and hence Collections.sort() between JDK 6 and JDK 7. The difference resides in the new algorythm that should perform 20% less swaps. That's probably this swap operation that made things work under JDK6 and JDK7.

If I may you are "looking for trouble" if you rename only one mock field of the fields that have the same type (or same erasure). When mocks cannot be differentiated by type you really should name all your mock field to corresponding field, but the Javadoc does not state that clearly.

Thanks a lot for reporting that odd behavior by the way, I created an [issue on Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=353), however for now I won't really solve this issue, but rather ensure the same behavior across JDKs. Solving this situation might need to code a new algorythm while maintaining compatibility, in the mean time you should name all your field mocks accordingly to the fields of tested class.

For now the thing to do will probably be tweaking the comparator with additional comparisons to enforce the same order on JDK6 and JDK7. Plus adding some warning in the Javadoc.

**EDIT** : Making two passes might solve the problem for most people.

Hope that helps. Thx for spotting the issue.

---

Also by the way you need either `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` or the runner `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, using both is not necessary, and might even cause some problems. :)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I realised I was sort of _looking for trouble_ but the difference between JDK6 and JDK7 was a real problem recently. Thanks for the clarification, the tip of not using both `initMocks()` and `@RunWith` and raising the issue officially.

Comment: @andyb The issue is fixed in trunk :)

Answer (score 2):

Mockito's behaviour is undefined, if there's more than one mock that matches one of the fields that is going to be injected.  Here, "matches" means it's the right type, ignoring any type parameters - type erasure prevents Mockito from knowing about the type parameters.  So in your example, either of the two mocks could be injected into either of the two fields.

The fact that you've managed to observe different behaviour with Java 6 from Java 7 is a bit of a red herring.  There is no reason, in either version of Java, to expect Mockito to choose correctly between `mockStringString` or `mockStringInteger`, for either one of the two fields that it's injecting.

Comment: I'm curious, it says in the docs "Mockito tries to inject by type (using name in case types are the same)."  Why doesn't it use the name here to break the tie between two fields of the same type?

Comment: Hmm, that may be an error in the documentation.  I know that the behaviour of InjectMocks changed a little in 1.9.0, and maybe we forgot to change the documentation at the same time.  I shall discuss it with the rest of the Mockito team and see if I can find out what happened.  It certainly seems reasonable that it SHOULD use the name in cases like this; but I've checked the code and I'm pretty sure that it doesn't.  I will keep you apprised of what I find out.

Comment: Sorry something came up and I haven't been able to look at this any more. Thanks for your answer. Ironically when I first found this in some real code, the opposite was occurring. Java 6 compiled/run code was not being injected as expected and Java 7 equivalent was working.

Comment: To be clear, I am looking at it again now. Should have said "look at this any more until now" in my previous comment :-)

Comment: Actually, there is no type erasure in this test. Full type information is available both though ASM and through the Reflection API. If Mockito doesn't use it, then it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this correct**?

Indeed, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), Mockito can't see the difference between the various Maps at run time / via reflection, which is giving Mockito a hard time doing the proper injection.

The `null` response to `stringString.get("foo")` can have two causes:

1. stringString properly mocked, but stubbing did not take place (`get` always return `null`).
2. stringString not mocked, so still a `HashMap` without a value for `"foo"`, so `get` will return `null`.

The `{}` response to the `stringInteger` variable means it has been initialized (in the class) with an actual (empty) `HashMap`.

So what your output tells you is that `stringInteger` is not mocked. What about `stringString`?

If none of the two `@Mock`s have names that match any of the fields of the class under test, nothing is mocked. The reason? I suspect it can't decide which field to inject into, so it doesn't do any mocking. You can verify this by displaying both variables, which will both yield `{}`. This explains your `null` value.

If one of the `@Mock`s has a name that matches, and the other has one that doesn't (your modification, one `mockedStringString` and one `stringInteger`, i.e., having the same name), what should Mockito do?

What you want it to do is only inject one of them and only in the field *with the corresponding name*. In your case, you have `mockedStringString` (you would expect this not to match) and `stringInteger` (you would expect it to match). Since you stubbed the `mockedStringString` (!), which won't match, *the expected outcome would be `null`*.

In other words, I think the Java 7 response is OK, and the Java 6 one is not OK, for the specific example given.

To see what is going on for the (unexpected) behavior you get for Java 6, try having just one `@Mock` -- if I properly mock `stringString` and have *no* mock for `stringInteger`, the mock for for `stringString` is injected into the `stringInteger` field. In other words, Mockito seems to first figure out that it can inject (given the name), and then injects the mock to one of the matching possibilities (but not necessarily the right one).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have tried just one `@Mock` locally as well. I understand (and have read in the documentation) what mockito might be doing behind the scenes when trying to inject mocks but am still not convinced why Java 6 and 7 are behaving differently. You say you _think_ the Java 7 response is OK but I think that is it wrong and should be injected and really want to understand _why_. I realise I can make the problem go away with better mocked object names, but that's not the point :-)

Comment: Why I think it is right: In your example code after the modification, you have `stringInteger` and `mockStringString`. Hence *stringString* should **not** be found in any implementation (but `stringInteger` should!), which is why I think `null` is an OK answer.

Comment: But: if your edit would be to replace `mockedStringString` by the matching `stringString` and leave the rest the same, I would expect the mocking to occur and `bar` to be displayed.

Comment: You're right: I only have an answer to the *Is this correct* part of your question. Equally curious to the difference between Java 6 and Java behavior here, but I don't know. I could not easily reproduce it (I tried within Eclipse using different JRE versions).